# Filter Twitter by application used

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to filter Twitter search results by the application used to post the tweet? For example, if I only wanted to see results from users using TweetDeck, or some other API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `source` operator

`inception source:tweetdeck`

returns http://twitter.com/#search?q=inception%20source%3Atweetdeck

For more operators check the [Search Operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/twitter/info) List

Comment: I wanted to ask this question, too. Thanks @phwd. But, can it search only among those people I follow? 

I wonder if Twitter API allows us to draw a pie chart that shows which Twitter client has highest popularity.

Comment: @mgthantzin yeah right now I do not think there is anything that does that without going into the API by yourself. The closest app (searching within friends) is [snapbird](http://snapbird.org/). Maybe you can try forking it.